# How to add component from another plugin to rendered partial

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I have my own plugin and I need to add a component from another plugin and use it in rendered partial. In my component I use this code:

```
return ['#list' => $this->renderPartial('loungelist::list.htm', [
    'paid_data' => $paid_result, 'list_data' => $result]),
        '#map' => $this->renderPartial('loungelist::map.htm', [
    'paid_data' => $paid_result, 'list_data' => $result])];
```

I need to use component `openingHours` by `OFFLINE` in partial list.htm. It doesn't work - it's only usable in default.htm, and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you would need to initialize the openingHours component again before return so the partial has the data. I usually provide the data manually when doing something like this. In essence, the `onRun()` function in OpeningHours.php needs to run again if you're displaying that component in an updated partial. If you provided `$this['locations']` prior to return, it should work. Something I usually forget: if you're using a partial in a partial, be sure to pass the data you need via Twig.

Comment: I tried to use smth like `$this->page['locations'] = Location::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get()` in the `onRun()` function and didn't work. What do you mean about pass the data via Twig? I am new in programming Laravel.

Comment: You'd want to use `$this->page['locations']` in a `onStart()` function on the page you're displaying the data on rather than in a `onRun()` function.When updating the partial, try `$this['locations']` instead of `$this->page['locations']`. On the page you're showing the partial, add `locations=this.page.locations` to the `{% partial %}` code in your HTML.  `$this->page['locations']` will pass the data when the page loads, `$this['locations']` will pass the data when the partial updates.

Comment: Well, thx. But it would be better to access not in .php file but only in my .htm partial. I want to use this tag `{{ openingHours.locationsBySlug[{{name}}].openingHours.isOpen() ? '<span class="badge badge-success">Open</span>' : '<span class="badge badge-danger">Close</span>' }}`. When I use it in default.htm it works but in partial plugin .htm file not.